# Adding additional swift files to flutter native packages

Tags: swift, flutter

I am trying to create a native package for flutter Swift/Kotlin, I built the UIViewController in a XCode project and moving the code to the flutter ios plugin therefore I added the MediaPickerController.swift file (as seen in the screenshot below).

[image]

In my SwiftMediaFilePickerPlugin.swift, I am trying to present the MediaPickerController but I am getting the "error: cannot find 'MediaPickerController' in scope"

The snippet of how I am presenting the MediaPickerController in SwiftMediaFilePickerPlugin.swift:-

```
let mediaPickerController = MediaPickerController(mediaType: mediaType, limit: limit)

UIViewController.topViewController().present(mediaPickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)

fileprivate extension UIViewController {
    class func topViewController(base: UIViewController? = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        if let presented = base?.presentedViewController {
            return topViewController(base: presented)
        }
        return base
    }
}
```

The code is working fine on a seperate swift project

Comment: Did you figure it out? I am struggling with same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Open `example/ios/Runner.xcworkspace` in Xcode and add additional files to `Pods/Development Pods/.../ios/Classes`.